# Oracle Shutdown error ORA-01033

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, oracle11gr2

I had installed Oracle 11g on windows 07,everything was working fine.But today it is giving me an error saaying **ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress** . I followed the steps mentioned in the different communities but unable to solve the error. After connecting as **sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba**. and executing below statement,i got following error. How to solve this error?

```
SQL> recover database;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 9: 'C:\APP\MKHATAL\ORADATA\ORCL\VELODBDATA.DBF'
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 9 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 9: 'C:\APP\MKHATAL\ORADATA\ORCL\VELODBDATA.DBF'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: An initialization or shutdown is in progress... this needs to finish first. You need to find out who or what initialized the shutdown and whether it's actually happening. I would imagine if you just wait a little bit it should be fine. How long have you waited?

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh........finally solved it after executing following commands  SQL>alter database datafile 29 OFFLINE DROP;
SQL>alter database open;

Answer (score 1):

First, check your ALERT.LOG file typically located in *D:\app\oracle\diag\rdbms\DBNAME\SID\trace\*.

The latest entries in your ALERT.LOG should give you an indication on what is going on. Is the database starting? Shutting down?

Should the database be stuck in the shutdown  process, you can try to kill the *oracle.exe* process and then restart the database via Windows Service.

Often, when the database seems to hang on startup, it is actually applying REDO to get a consistent state, so pay close attention on what the ALERT.LOG tells you.

Comment: Don't just kill the oracle.exe process. Leave it running for a while, in particular : 1 hour. Each SHUTDOWN statement has a limit of 1 hour built-in.

Answer (score 1):

There's more info needed to be able to solve similar issues. Questions like these are interesting to get answered:

- To what level can you start the database ? None, nomount, mount or
  open (exclude the last one in this case)
- What does the ALERT.LOG file show ? This from the moment the first
  issue is suspected to be around
- An obvious question is just : what happened ? What action were you
  doing when you saw the first error message ?
- Can you shutdown the database ? If yes, which methods : normal,
  immediate or abort only ? Know that stopping the database with ABORT
  option may make problems bigger as they are already.
- Did you try rebooting the server ? This is particularly an issue on
  Windows, which is your case.
- Depending on how you stopped the database, do you have a cold backup
  ?
- Depending on RMAN still working : can you take a backup ? The RECOVERY you were trying is not bad, but it could be interesting to know what is happening on OS level with that file; Is it there ? If yes, is it locked or not ? Does the OS think it's a valid file ?